# Php artisan queue:work not working but job are inserted

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, queue

I am troubling with php artisan queue::work command.

My command not working but my jobs are inserted into job table but never executing.

I am using mongodb driver for queue.

What I am doing wrong please suggest me.

Answer (score 9):

After spending half day on searching I noticed that queues do not run on maintenance mode. You have to put `--force` at the end of it.

> --force                Force the worker to run even in maintenance mode

So run `php artisan queue:work --force` in order to run queues on maintenance mode.

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#maintenance-mode for details.

Comment: Saved my day. Literally spent half a day analysing whats wrong with redis, then with database...

Comment: you are my savior

Answer (score 2):

I was having the similar issue. The Jobs were being inserted into jobs table in MySql DB, but  `php artisan queue:work` didn't pick those up.

In my case the queue was named (queue column value in jobs table) 'priority'.

So i had to run the queue:work command differently:

```
php artisan queue:work --daemon --queue=priority
```

But careful that above command only executes jobs in `priority` queue; You can add more queue names if needed like so `--queue=priority,queue_3,queue_4`

I was expecting `queue:work` without `--queue=` value to pickup any pending jobs.

Turns out, I was wrong. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Since this thread is a little bit old, I'll share my experience of it.

There is an error which is not obvious to find but corresponding to this condition. You can check your table `jobs`, and in Laravel the jobs should have literally been removed if your `queue:work` works well, so the problem is that your queue cannot deal with the top job in your table. It may be a problem of serializable data in db.

To solve it, you can try clearing the table **`jobs`** and **reset the 'incremental `id`'** from `~0`. On the other hand, you can also check your data sequence. This may be helpful after resetting the table.